# LVM - Volume Group - What are Extents?

Tags: lvm

What are `extents`?

For example, the command:

```
vgcreate -s 16M vg1 /dev/sda7 /dev/sda8
```

creates a Volume Group, vg1. Am I right in saying that `extents` are like buckets?

i.e. we're setting a 16M bucket size?

And can anyone refer me to some simple documentation on `extents`. E.g. this page:

https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Cluster_Logical_Volume_Manager/VG_create.html just mentions

**This extent is the minimum amount by which the logical volume may be increased or decreased in size.**

but doesn't say why it's called an `extent`, whether a Volume Group extent is the same as a Logical Volume extent, etc...

Any help?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

LVM breaks up each physical volume into extents. A logical volume consists of a set of extents. Each extent is either wholly unused, or wholly in used by a particular logical volume: extents cannot be subdivided. Extents are the elementary blocks of LVM allocation.

I don't know why the word *extent* was chosen.